# How to a edit an existing mapping in ODI using groovy

Tags: groovy, oracle-data-integrator

I'm trying to figure out how to use groovy to edit existing mapping.

I am able to create new mapping.  I tried to remove the delete portion of the code but it would give me an error that I need to delete exiting mapping

```
//delete old mapping
/* remove delete portion to use edit existing mapping
  removeMapping(folder, mappingName)

  txnDef = new DefaultTransactionDefinition()
  tm = odiInstance.getTransactionManager()
  tme = odiInstance.getTransactionalEntityManager()
  txnStatus = tm.getTransaction(txnDef)

  dsf = (IOdiDataStoreFinder)tme.getFinder(OdiDataStore.class)
  mapf = (IMappingFinder) tme.getFinder(Mapping.class)
*/
//create new mapping
  map = new Mapping(mappingName, folder);
  tme.persist(map)
```

From the error it seems like the mapping (Load_TRG_CUSTOMER) must be delete.
Please let me know if you need more code.

Error:

```
ODI-16096: A mapping with name Load_TRG_CUSTOMER already exists in folder TEST_FOLDER.
(Subtract 18 from the error line number to account for the standard imports)
oracle.odi.domain.mapping.exception.MappingException: ODI-16096: A mapping with name Load_TRG_CUSTOMER already exists in folder TEST_FOLDER.
    at oracle.odi.domain.mapping.Mapping.checkName(Mapping.java:153)
```

Thank you for everyone's help.

Comment: The error is there because you create a new Mapping object with the same name and same folder as an existing one. Instead of creating a new Mapping, you should find the existing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IMappingFinder](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/odi/reference-java-api/oracle/odi/domain/mapping/finder/IMappingFinder.html) provides useful methods to find an existing mapping. As you already know the name and folder, I guess that the [findByName](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/odi/reference-java-api/oracle/odi/domain/mapping/finder/IMappingFinder.html#findByName-oracle.odi.domain.adapter.project.IFolder-java.lang.String-) method is the best suited for you.

I see you already have an IMappingFinder instanciated (although it's commented at the moment). So you only need to replace  :

```
map = new Mapping(mappingName, folder);
```

by

```
map = (Mapping) mapf.findByName(folder, mappingName);
```

Comment: Thank you Jerome.  I have a current connection my source to my target.  I'm add another connect from the same source and target.  I can't seem to figure out how to do it.  It keeps creating a new source and target.  Have you done this before by chance?